# SharePoint authentication Custom Login form

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2013, And its configured with Windows authentication, I do not have form based authentication.  I want user's to login through login form rather than windows popup for login.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this similar question here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7270c7f-7ddb-4ec6-8564-9ef4ab11bd6c/custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answered by Trevor:

> By definition, Windows Authentication will prompt for credentials with
> a pop-up. Any 'custom logon page' will require forms-based
> authentication